# upload zip file to Node.js via Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, forms, xmlhttprequest

How to load zip files to the server node js without forms, just using ajax, and unpack this.

I'm trying to do it like:

```
    function sendAjax(request) {       
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open(request.method, request.url);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200){
            if (request.callback) {
                request.callback(JSON.parse(xhr.response));
            }
        }
    };
    var data = null;
    if (request.multipleData !== true) {
        data = JSON.stringify(request.data);
    } else {
        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append('file.zip', request.data);
        data = fd;
    }
    xhr.send(data);
}
```

on the server side I'm doing next:

```
 var body = '';
    request.on('data', function (data) {console.log(1111 + data);
        body += data;
        // 1e6 === 1 * Math.pow(10, 6) === 1 * 1000000 ~~~ 1MB
        if (body.length > 1e8) { 
            // FLOOD ATTACK OR FAULTY CLIENT, NUKE REQUEST
            request.connection.destroy();
        }
    });
    request.on('end', function () {console.log(222 + body);
        router.route(url.parse(request.url, true), response, body);
    });
```

and

```
var buf = new Buffer(file.length);
    buf.write(file);
    var zip = new AdmZip(buf);
    var zipEntries = zip.getEntries(); // an array of ZipEntry records
    for (var i = 0; i < zipEntries.length; i++) {
        console.log(zip.file("content.txt").asText());
```

But I'm getting error,

...server\node_modules\adm-zip\zipFile.js:66
            throw Utils.Errors.INVALID_FORMAT;
                              ^
Invalid or unsupported zip format. No END header found

What the problem?